# Binding an event to the "tab" button via knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'd like to call a method if the user "tabs" out of a field.  It shouldn't be called when focus is lost or when the user clicks elsewhere - only if they tab out of the field.  Does knockout make this especially easy by any chance, or should I start digging into some kind of jQuery solution?

Comment: Knockout can handle this the same way jQuery would: by checking the `keycode` value for `tab` in any of the `key` events (down,press,up).

Comment: ah, thanks Ty.  Feel free to make your comment an answer and I can accept it, or I can delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the event binding to do this, here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaX2Q/)

```
<input data-bind="event: { keydown: tabOut}" />


var ViewModel = function() {
    this.tabOut = function(data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 9) {
            console.log("tab was pressed");
        };
        return true;
    };
};
```

Comment: After providing keydown event binding in knockout, the Tab key stopped working. That is now focus does not move to next control on pressing tab, any idea why this is happening or how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I resolved the Tab key not working problem, just needed to add "return true" in my event handler.